# Refine PHP WSDL Soap client results and export to csv

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I have created a PHP script that queries a WSDL Soap service. I can get the correct results returned. I was looking to know how would I go about refining the results to show only one value and having the abilty to export these to a CSV? This what it returns when I use `print_r($response)`:

```
stdClass Object ( [data] => stdClass Object (
          [array] => stdClass Object (
                     [articleLinkages] => stdClass Object (
                                          [array] => Array (
                                                     [0] => stdClass Object (
                                                            [articleLinkId] => 18973666 
                                                            [linkingTargetId] => 29480 
                                                            [linkingTargetType] => P 
                                                            ) 
                                                     [1] => stdClass Object (
                                                            [articleLinkId] => 18973667 
                                                            [linkingTargetId] => 29481 
                                                            [linkingTargetType] => P 
                                                            ) 
                                                     [2] => stdClass Object (
                                                            [articleLinkId] => 18973683 
                                                            [linkingTargetId] => 29482 
                                                            [linkingTargetType] => P 
                                                            ) 
                                                     [3] => stdClass Object (
                                                            [articleLinkId] => 18973763 
                                                            [linkingTargetId] => 34928 
                                                            [linkingTargetType] => P 
                                                            ) 
                                                     [4] => stdClass Object (
                                                            [articleLinkId] => 18973699 
                                                            [linkingTargetId] => 29483 
                                                            [linkingTargetType] => P 
                                                            ) 
                                                     [5] => stdClass Object (
                                                            [articleLinkId] => 18973715 
                                                            [linkingTargetId] => 29484 
                                                            [linkingTargetType] => P 
                                                            )
                                                     [6] => stdClass Object (
                                                            [articleLinkId] => 18973731 
                                                            [linkingTargetId] => 29485 
                                                            [linkingTargetType] => P 
                                                            ) 
                                                     [7] => stdClass Object (
                                                            [articleLinkId] => 18973779 
                                                            [linkingTargetId] => 34929 
                                                            [linkingTargetType] => P 
                                                            ) 
                                                 ) 
                     ) 
          )  ) 
          [status] => 200  )
```

I only want to see the `linkingTargetId` values. Like this.

```
29480,
29481,
29482,
34928,
29483,
29484,
29485,
34929,
```

and be able to export these to a csv? Would this be difficult to achieve?

Comment: You just need do use [foreach function](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). Something, like `foreach($response->data->array->articleLinkages['array'] as $linkage){echo $linkage->linkingTargetId;}`

Comment: I dont think soap/wsdl has any bearing on this question. The question should be: How do I show a single value from a `stdClass` object and export a `stdClass` object to a csv